# Show that if G is a connected simple k-regular graph with k ≥ 2 and χ'(G) = k, then G is Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

Hi I am really lost on this problem. The notation χ'(G) = k means that the graph has a proper edge coloring of size k. I am only to the point where I know our graph G is comprised of cycles, and has an even number of vertices. If it is K color-able then every vertex has k edges of distinct colors. The edges then must be adjacent to other edges of a different colors incident to a different vertex. I feel intuitively if we follow this pattern we will get a cycle that hits all the vertices. Any insight or help would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Such a graph is $1$-factorizable, and it seems to me that there should exist a pair of $1$-factors whose union induces a Hamiltonian cycle. But I'm not sure how to prove that.

Comment: @Math1000 That's not true, just consider a cube with each direction X,Y,Z colored different way. You have to use all the three colors to get the Hamilton cycle.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of searching, I've found [this graph](https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=6921):

[image: https://hog.grinvin.org/ViewGraphInfo.action?id=6921]

which is a cubic, connected, non-Hamiltonian graph with chromatic index $3$. 
Another counterexample could be also the [Barnette-Bosák-Lederberg Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Barnette-Bosak-LederbergGraph.html) which is also planar.

No wonder you can't prove it, the claim is false.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$